# Output of cron on the ssh shell ?

Tags: cron, reboot

**OS:** Centos 7 |
**Shell:** Bash |
**Virtual Machine:** Virtualbox

I have created a short script to check few servers on startup of my application and need to run this on every reboot.

I have configured the crontab to run it every reboot however i am not seeing the output on the shell.

```
@reboot /home/admin/scripts/connection.sh
```

What am i missing in setting this up ?

Comment: ... why would cron's output show in your shell?

Comment: I wasn't sure it would or not! How can i run this to show once i login on the system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cronjob's output does not go to the shell. Most often, the output written to its standard output and standard error streams are collected and *mailed* to the owner of the cronjob.

To log the output to a file:

```
@reboot /home/admin/scripts/connection.sh >>/home/admin/connection.log 2>&1
```

This will make all output from the script be appended to the file `/home/admin/connection.log`.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, Thank you! I will try your suggestion, for the time i added the script to the bashrc and it worked. 

Appreciate the response!

Comment: @Atul Adding the script to the `~/.bashrc` file will make it run for once _each new shell session_ (i.e. twice if your open two terminals).